# How should i use async await between my business/service/application layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

Right now my methods look something like this.

ProductManager class in business

```
public static async Task<List<ProductItem>> GetAllProducts()
{
    var context = GetMyContext();
    return await context.Products.select(x => 
    new ProductItem{ //create item})
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

ProductService class in service.

```
public async Task<List<ProductItem>> GetAllProducts()
{
  return await ProductManager.GetAllProducts();
}
```

ProductController in application.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var ps = new ProductService();
  var productsAsync = ps.GetAllProducts();
  // Do other work.
  var products = await productsAsync;
  return View(products);
}
```

This application gets high usage, 
Is this way of doing it totally wrong ? 
Should I be await every method ?
Will this start a new thread every time await is called ?

Comment: `await` simply awaits for something to complete. If you don't need the results of a task in your method, you don't need to await it. `GetAllProducts` should simply return the results of `ToListAsync`

Comment: "Will this start a new thread every time await is called?" This is a common misconception - `await` doesn't *start* anything. All it does is *dutifully* wait for a `Task` or task-like object to finish whatever it has *already* started. *How* that `Task` is achieving it's job (starting a thread, queueing I/O, etc) is entirely the responsibility of the method that handed your code back a `Task`.

Comment: First, `ProductService` here is pointless. Either do the work in the service method, or just use `ProductManager` directly. All you're doing here is managing two duplicate APIs. Second, just do `var products = await ps.GetAllProducts();`. There's no need to save the Task to a variable first. Finally, heed the advice of @PanagiotisKanavos below: if your method itself returns a Task, don't await anything inside. Just return the Task. (Unless, you actually need to do something with the Task result in that method.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This application gets high usage, Is this way of doing it totally wrong?

No; it looks good to me.

> Should I be await every method?

Yes. Once you put in the first `await` (in `ProductManager`), then its callers should be `await`ed, and their callers `await`ed, and so on, up to the controller action method. This "growth" of `async` is entirely natural; it's called "[async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" in my MSDN article on async best practices.

> Will this start a new thread every time await is called?

No. `Await` is about freeing up threads, not using more threads. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that describes how `async` and `await` work.

Answer (score 1):

`await` simply awaits for something to complete. If you don't need the results of a task in your method, you don't need to await it. `GetAllProducts` should simply return the results of `ToListAsync`.

```
public static Task<List<ProductItem>> GetAllProducts()
{
    var context = GetMyContext();
    return context.Products
                  .Select(x => new ProductItem{ //create item})
                  .ToListAsync();
}
```

`async/await` adds a bit of overhead, since the compiler has to generate a state machine that stores the original synchronization context, waits for the awaited task to finish and then restores the original synchronization context.

Adding `async/await` on a method that doesn't need to process the result of the task simply adds overhead. In fact, there are some Roslyn analyzers that detect and fix this issue